# What is mtcnn face recognition power?

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition, face-detection

i am working on oneshot learning for face recognition first I have to detect face in frame, I use this with mtcnn but it does not work properly... i want to know the power of mtcnn. Can it recognize half-faces and three faces with different lighting?
what is the best face detection model now?

Answer (score 0):

currently, retinaface is the cutting edge facial detector. [Here](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/blob/master/resources/11513D05.jpg), you can see its testing results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes mtcnn can detect partially covered faces and multiple faces in an image. Retinaface is better than MTCNN. [SCRFD](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/tree/master/detection/scrfd) is better than Retinaface.